# How to fix ui three dots in center line text overflow flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have code like this :

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          S.current.lbl_consignee_type + ": ",
          style: AppTextStyle.caption2,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            getStringAddress(consignee),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: AppTextStyle.caption2,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            softWrap: true,
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

if like flutter docs when text overflow will have UI like: text...
but my ui like this [Err UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8XrQ.png)

How I can  fix that, I want this show UI normal like text...

Comment: Probably by removing `textAlign: TextAlign.center`
Also consider using `Text.rich` instead of `Row` with several `Text`s

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom 3 dots by simply remove this line :

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

and after expanded do something like:

```
Icon(Icons.more_horiz);
```